# glm result difference between multiple number of bootstrap simulations vs. one simulation based on mulstiple boostrap measurements

Tags: generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, resampling

I am performing  1000 bootstrap iterations on my data. For each iteration, there are 18 measurements included in the sample, and I would perform GLM after each iteration. So in total, I get 1000 GLM results, and I would use the mean coefficients from all GLM results as my final coefficient values.

But I have a question, if I store the sample measurements of each iteration (so at last, I would have a sample size of 18 * 1000), then I only need to perform the GLM analysis one time based on the total sample size from all bootstrap iterations, and only get one coefficient summary.

So will there be any robustness differences between these two approaches?

I appreciate any explanations, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the bootstrap is that it does not merely yield a point estimator, but also an estimator for its variance or even directly a non-paramteric confidence interval.

In ["Bootstrap Methods for Standard Errors, Confidence Intervals, and Other Measures of Statistical Accuracy"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-1/issue-1/Bootstrap-Methods-for-Standard-Errors-Confidence-Intervals-and-Other-Measures/10.1214/ss/1177013815.full), Efron and Tibshirani write:

> Why is each bootstrap sample size taken with the same size $n$ as the original dataset? [...]
> The Monte Carlo algorithm will not converge to $\hat{\sigma}$
> if the bootstrap sample differs from the treu $n$. Bickel and Friedman (1981) show how to correct the algorithm to give $\hat{\sigma}$
> if in fact the bootstrap sample size is taken different than $n$,
> but so far there does not seem to be any practical advantage to be gained this way.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: If an answer actually answers your question, you should accept it as an answer so that the thread is marked as "answerd".